# SQL Server stored procedure couldn't be found

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am making a project in C# and I have connected to my SQL Server 2008 database. I created a procedure but I keep getting error that it couldn't be found. Funny thing is that I created 2 more procedures in same script and everything works fine.

First I read script and execute all code, and that passes very well, then one table is created and 2 procedures and finally I come to my last procedure but it keep's giving me error. I'll put some code so you guys can see what have I done wrong.

```
IF object_id('Uporabniki') IS NULL
CREATE TABLE Uporabniki
    (
        id_uporabnika int,
        ime_uporabnika nvarchar(200) not NULL,
        skupina_uporabnika nvarchar(200) not NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (id_uporabnika)
    )
GO

IF object_id('Dodaj_uporabnika') IS NULL
EXEC sp_executesql N'
CREATE PROCEDURE Dodaj_uporabnika
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @ime_uporabnika nvarchar(200),
    @skupina_uporabnika nvarchar(200)

AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @id_konec INT
        SET @id_konec=(SELECT MAX(id_uporabnika) FROM Uporabniki);
        IF(@id_konec IS NULL)
            BEGIN
                SET @id_konec= 1
                insert into Uporabniki (id_uporabnika,ime_uporabnika, skupina_uporabnika) values (@id_konec, @ime_uporabnika,@skupina_uporabnika);
            END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            insert into Uporabniki (id_uporabnika,ime_uporabnika, skupina_uporabnika) values (@id_konec + 1, @ime_uporabnika,@skupina_uporabnika);
        END
END'
GO

IF object_id('Spremeni_uporabnika') IS NULL

EXEC sp_executesql N'
CREATE PROCEDURE Spremeni_uporabnika
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @stari_id int,
    @novo_ime_uporabnika nvarchar(200),
    @nova_skupina_uporabnika nvarchar(200)

AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Uporabniki SET ime_uporabnika=@novo_ime_uporabnika,skupina_uporabnika=@nova_skupina_uporabnika WHERE @stari_id=id_uporabnika;
    END
END'
GO

IF object_id('Brisanje_uporabnika') IS NULL

EXEC sp_executesql N'
CREATE PROCEDURE Brisanje_uporabnika
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @id_uporabnika int

AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        DELETE * FROM Uporabniki WHERE @id_uporabnika = id_uporabnika;
    END
END'
GO
```

Comment: You've got two problems - the scripting, and the fact of using dynamic SQL...

Comment: Have you checked the procedure schema? Add the schema to the call and see what happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DELETE * FROM Uporabniki` is invalid syntax so `Brisanje_uporabnika` will never be created.

use

`DELETE  FROM Uporabniki` instead. Not sure how you are submitting this script but you should see the following error when you run it.

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Brisanje_uporabnika, Line 9
>
> Incorrect syntax near '*'.

Comment: @Denonth: if that answer solved your problem, please get in the habit of **accepting** that answer. It's the right and polite thing to do on StackOverflow and serves as an incentive for others to continue to help those looking for answers. [See the FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/accepting-answers-what-is-it-all-about)